# Side bar in hamburger menu isn't showing

Tags: html, css

I wrote a code from tutorial on making hamburger menu with sidebar when on clicking with the help of checkbox
but sidebar isn't showing except underlined text

You can also see here: https://codepen.io/mak_developer/pen/ExpJVLM

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px -50px 0 0px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.menu {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger_menu">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="hamburger_line1"></div>
  <div class="hamburger_line2"></div>
  <div class="hamburger_line3"></div>
  <header id="menu">
    <div><a href="#">Home </a></div>
    <div><a href="#">About</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Info </a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
    <div><a href="#" target="_blank">Show me more</a></div>
  </header>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: In CSS you are using `.menu`, but in HTML `menu` is the id, not the class name

Comment: replace in html `<header id="menu">` with `<header id="menu" class="menu">` or change your css `.menu {` to `header#menu {`-> you are mixing class-name and id.